# Creates a logical vector that checks if the row name contains a string " "

Tags: r, vector

I have a dataset which looks like this

```
                 col1   col2   col3
    1 MALE       ...     ...    ...
    2 MALE       
    3 FEMALE     ...     
    4 MALE
    5 FEMALE     ...
```

where the rownames(dataset) returns

```
    "1 MALE" "2 MALE" "3 FEMALE" ...
```

I want to create a logical vector that selects the rows of MALE, how can I do this?
I am not familiar with the "grep" function
Thanks!

Comment: Assuming `df` is your dataframe: `grepl("MALE", rownames(df))`

Comment: That would return TRUE for all the rownames as FEMALE contains the regex MALE

Comment: Very true @jruf003, thanks for pointing that out. I was too fast. This should work `grepl("\\sMALE", rownames(df))`.

Comment: Or just use a boundary.  `grepl("\\bMALE", c("MALE", "FEMALE"))`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all your rownames have a space immediately preceding "MALE" as per your example, you could do it like this: `grepl(" MALE", rownames(X))`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
library("dplyr")
library("tibble")
library("stringr")

df %>%
    rownames_to_column %>%
    filter(str_detect("MALE", rowname))
```